# How do I change the font type in the table of contents in LyX

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, lyx, fontspec

Hi all I would like to change the font type of my table of contents of a document written in LyX to Calibri (I have it installed and the rest of my document is in calibri)

Document class: Article
Page Size : A4

Thanks

My Table of contents:
[image]

The font I want:
[image]

Minimal working code:

```
%% LyX 2.3.6.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{By}
\author{Author}

\maketitle
\newpage

\tableofcontents{}

\newpage

\section{Section 1}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can't post a minimal working example as the article is written in a software called LyX.

Comment: @Aurelius_nero LyX is just an unusual frontend to LaTeX. Create a new document with the same template and font settings as the one you're working on, but as minimal as possible. One or two dummy sections and subsections with a sentence in each, and a TOC, which replicates this problem. Export it to LaTeX from the File menu > Export and post it here. (Probably LaTeX (XeTeX) for Calibri.) As is, none of us can even understand why your TOC is in a typewriter font to begin with, much less how to change it. That's not default. You must have done something to make it do that. We need to know what.

Comment: @Aurelius_nero Please read this LyX-specific information about a MWE: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Did LyX really produce a document without `\end{document}` at the end? Anyway, fixing that, that document doesn't show the problem, at least for me anyway. Assuming it doesn't for you either, keep transferring parts of your working document into the new document bit by bit until the problem shows up. Then remove everything before the last thing you transferred until all that's left is what causes the problem.